# How do I fix this error? Syntax error near "assign"

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to make a 2x1 mux in Verilog, with the variation that each input is actually technically 2 inputs, and same goes for the output. However, it still behaves like a 2x1 mux. My code looks like this:

```
module mux                                                      
(
  output [11:0] out_0,
  output [11:0] out_1,
  input sel,
  input [11:0] in_a_i,
  input [11:0] in_b_i,
  input [11:0] in_a_q,               
  input [11:0] in_b_q
)                    
  assign out_0 = (sel) ? in_a_i : in_b_i;             
  assign out_1 = (sel) ? in_a_q : in_b_q;                          
endmodule
```

When I try to build this in Xilinx, I'm given the error:

> Syntax error near "assign"

I don't understand what's wrong with the assign line.  Am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a semicolon (`;`) after the `module` declaration.

```
module mux
(
  output [11:0] out_0,
  output [11:0] out_1,
  input sel,
  input [11:0] in_a_i,
  input [11:0] in_b_i,
  input [11:0] in_a_q,               
  input [11:0] in_b_q
)  ;
```